# I have set up oauth2 properties in application.properties, How to use them in the code?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, google-oauth, properties-file

In my Spring boot application I am using google oauth2 to get users signed in from their gmail account. I have obtained and set the client id, secret and scope using my account details and tested the program. 
 But now I need to run this in a separate environment so all the hard coded configurations must be gone. 
 I added the client id , seceret and scope in my **application.properties** file as follows,

```
security.oauth2.client.id= 5******-5**bd***a6.apps.googleusercontent.com
security.oauth2.client.client-secret=m******qb***H
security.oauth2.client.scope[0]=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly
```

Now how to use this properties in my java class. for **example**

```
 public static String getToken() throws Exception {

    String clientId =  "5******-5**bd***a6.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    String clientSecret = "m******qb***H";
    String scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly ";

    AuthorizationCodeFlow flow=
            new AuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(BearerToken.authorizationHeaderAccessMethod(),
                    new NetHttpTransport(),
                    new JacksonFactory(),
                    new GenericUrl(GoogleOAuthConstants.TOKEN_SERVER_URL),
                    new BasicAuthentication(clientId, clientSecret),
                    clientId,
                    GoogleOAuthConstants.AUTHORIZATION_SERVER_URL)
                    .setScopes(Collections.singleton(scope)).build();
```

I want to create a config class and get the id,secret,scope values from the .properties file and then use those here. **All this should be done using Spring** not by file reading please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Value annotation as shown below to read the properties

```
@Value("${security.oauth2.client.id}")
private String clientId;
```